# USB 3.0/3.1 faster than 2.0 for Tails?

Tags: tails, speed

Are newer USB generations (3.0,3.1) faster than USB 2.0 when running Tails? Or will they be nearly the same?

Note, I am not asking about Persistent Storage read/write speed, but the actual OS run speed.

Comment: for sure USB 3.x should/can be faster than USB 2.0, but you may also suffer speed limits from the flash storage resp. its controller itself. - just because the connector of an USB stick is 2.0 or 3.x, it doesn't mean that it is also able to use the full speed potential of its connector.

Answer (score 1):

Tails uses the Debian Linux kernel which runs USB at the correct speed. That means that you can expect significantly faster speeds with USB 3 than USB 2.

The only caveat is that you have a machine with USB 3 ports and also USB 3 storage. If either is USB 2, then expect USB 2 speeds. This is the same on any modern operating system and has nothing to do with Tails.